# How to use .translate() correctly for the removal of non alphabetical either numerical characters?

Tags: python, dataframe, google-colaboratory, data-cleaning

I want to remove symbols (Most of them but not all) from my data column 'Review'.
A little background on my code:

```
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
# convert to lower case
data['Review'] = data['Review'].str.lower()
# remove trailing white spaces
data['Review'] = data['Review'].str.strip()
```

This is what I did based on what I read on the internet (I'm still on the beginner-level of NLP, so don't be surprised to find more than one mistake, I just want to know what are they):

```
import string
sep = '|'
punctuation_chars = '"#$%&\()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{}~'
mapping_table = str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys(punctuation_chars, ''))
 = sep.join(df[df(data['Review']).tolist()]).translate(mapping_table).split(sep)
```

However, I get the following error:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'tolist'

How could I solve it? I want to use .translate() because I read it's more efficient than other methods.

Answer (score 0):

The `AttributeError` is caused because `DataFrame.tolist()` doesn't exist. It looks like the code assumes that `df(data['Review'])` is a `Series`, but it is actually a `DataFrame`.

```py
df = DataFrame(data['Review'])
translated_reviews = sep.join(df[0].tolist()).translate(mapping_table).split(sep)
```

It's unclear whether `data` is a `DataFrame`. If it is, just use it in the `join()` without calling `tolist()` or instantiating a new `DataFrame`.

```py
translated_reviews = sep.join(data['Review']).translate(mapping_table).split(sep)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was where you were trying to create a dataframe object from a column of your data dataframe and then convert that to list `df[df(data['Review']).tolist()]` (that part). You can either use
`df.values.tolist()` which would convert the whole dataframe, df, to a list or if you just want to convert a column use `data['Review'].tolist()`

So in your situation the final line of your code would be switched to

```
data['Review'] = sep.join(data['Review'].tolist()).translate(mapping_table).split(sep)
```

Comment: It seemed about to work! However, it displays a different error now: ValueError: Length of values (2476577) does not match length of index (20491)

Comment: I found out the mistake: using the data['Review'] as the variable. Now it works!